# decimal accuracy error in c++

Tags: c++, decimal

I am writing a code to translate a decimal from unary to binary if it can be translated accurately, or return error message if it can't. Below are my codes. I am confused about decimal error. In one step, n before is 1.12, temp is 1, but the output is 0.12001, how to avoid this kind of error?

```
list<bool> binary_decimal(double n, bool& flag){
    list<bool> li;
    list<double> left;
    flag = true;
    n = n - (int)n;
    left.push_back(n);
    while(n){
        n = n * 2;
        cout << "n before " << n << endl;  //test area
        li.push_back(n >= 1);
        int temp = (int)n;
        cout << "temp " << temp << endl;  // test area
        n = n - temp;
        cout << "n now = " << n << endl;  //test area
        for(list<double>:: iterator it = left.begin(); it != left.end(); it++){
            if(*it == n){
                cout << "error!";
                flag = false;
                return li;
            }
        }
        left.push_back(n);
    }
    return li;
}
```

Comment: What is a *unary* number?

Comment: @ZacHowland http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system

Comment: although I'm not sure he is using the term correctly. How can a `double` be unary?

Comment: @EitanT So it is counting sticks?  That would be a simple `count` call on a `std::list` container ...

Comment: @ZacHowland We're all probably missing a detail here, so there's no point guessing until there's an example at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to floating-point rounding errors!

The number 0.12 is not expressible as a terminating binary fraction, so you get rounding errors.

You can calculate each digit explicitly to avoid the errors.  Think either along the lines of arbitrary precision arithmetic or "rolling your own" calculation engine.

Or, another alternative is to round to the number of places you need.  Here, four decimal places would be enough.